# iOS: Differences in Memory Usage on iPhone 4s and iPhone 5s

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, memory, unity-game-engine

We have differences in Memory Usage on iPhone 4s and iPhone 5s (Unity3D Application). I use the Memory graph/chart in Xcode for profile.

**Memory usage**

- iPhone 4s: 171 MB
- iPhone 5s: 104 MB

How can this happen? Should it not be larger memory usage on iPhone 5s (bigger graphics...).

Comment: Is that consistent across several runs? I'd be wary of garbage collection mucking around with your data.

Comment: This is consistent across several runs.

Comment: they both should use (almost) the same memory, because they both use retina graphics. on which iOS version are those iPhones?

Comment: iPhone 4s: iOS 7.0.3
iPhone 5s: iOS 7.0.4